# Explicit outer automorphism of indefinite unitary groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $L/K$ be a quadratic galois extension of fields. Denote the nontrivial automorphism of $L/K$ by $x\mapsto \overline{x}$, which we call ``conjugation''. Let $H\in GL_n(L)$ be a conjugate-symmetric matrix. Thus, we may speak of the unitary group $U_H$.

When $H$ satisfies $H = H^{-1}$, then the inverse-transpose $g\mapsto g^{-t}$ defines a non-inner automorphism of $U_H$. When $H$ satisfies $H = H^{-t}$, then the conjugate-inner-transpose defines a non-inner automorphism of $U_H$. Similarly when $H$ is (group-theoretically) conjugate to a matrix satisfying either of the two conditions, then again we can find a non-inner automorphism.

Does $U_H$ always have a non-inner automorphism?